# How to debug "Type initializer for 'WindowsFormsAutoClick.Form1' threw an exception."?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, dictionary, typeinitializationexception

I am trying to add a new Dictionary value and add a new User Control to a Flow Layout. But pressing the add control button throws an initializer exception with an inner exception such as "Key has already been added". I don't know the full exception because I am having difficulties with finding how to open the popup error that usually shows in Visual Studio.

Already set a loop to check if the key already is added to the dictionary and if so change the key (as shown in the code blocK).
Also tried clearing the flow layout controls list. (made no changes to the error)

Function were the error is thrown:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Create a new key propertie set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
private void buttonAddKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create new UI key component in the flow layout.
    KeyPropertiesCtrl inputKeyCtrl = new KeyPropertiesCtrl();
    flowLayoutKeys.Controls.Add(inputKeyCtrl);

    Console.WriteLine("inputKeyCtrl " + inputKeyCtrl.Name + " parent " + inputKeyCtrl.Parent.Name);

    // Create new data input key.
    CustomInputKey newKey = new CustomInputKey();
    newKey.Activation.InputKey = new Interception();

    Console.WriteLine("newKey " + newKey.Activation.InputKey);

    // Get a key binding from the user.
    try
    {
        Form1.Context = InterceptionDriver.CreateContext();

        InterceptionDriver.SetFilter(Form1.Context, InterceptionDriver.IsKeyboard, (Int32)KeyboardFilterMode.All);
        InterceptionDriver.SetFilter(Form1.Context, InterceptionDriver.IsMouse, (Int32)MouseFilterMode.All);

        Form1.InterceptOnce(Form1.Context, out newKey.Activation.InputKey.DeviceId, out newKey.Activation.InputKey.TheStroke);

        InterceptionDriver.DestroyContext(Form1.Context);


        // Change the key bind in UI text.
        if (newKey.Activation.InputKey.TheStroke.Key.State != 0)
            inputKeyCtrl.button1.Text = newKey.Activation.InputKey.TheStroke.Key.Code.ToString();
        else
            inputKeyCtrl.button1.Text = newKey.Activation.InputKey.TheStroke.Mouse.State.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    { Console.WriteLine(excp); }

    // Set the key bind in data list.
    string name = inputKeyCtrl.Name;
    byte attempts = 0;
    while (Form1.CurrentSelections.SelectedPreset.GetCustomKeys.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        if (attempts > 50)
        {
            break;
        }
        attempts++;
        name += attempts;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(this.Name + " name Attempts " + attempts + " name " + name);

    if (attempts < 50)
        Form1.CurrentSelections.SelectedPreset.AddKey(Form1.CurrentSelections.SelectedPresetName, name, newKey);
}
```

So What I actually expect is after pressing the button control. It creates a new User Control in a Flow Layout and then it freezes the application when it hits the function InterceptOnce() because there it will wait for me to press a input to bind that input. Finally store the new key bind and save the dictionary on to a file.

But it throws the exception "key has already been added" on the line of while(Form1.CurrentSelections...){} and before I added that while loop and the try{} the exception was thrown on Form1.Context = InterceptionDriver.CreateContext(); which is weird, because with the try{}catch(Exception excp){} it doesn't throw an exception. I think the exception has to do with new CustomInputKey(); and have no clue why...

Error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07DAf.png)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean and where I am supposed to look in the WindowsFormAutoClick, because WindowsFormAutoClick is the namespace of it all and I don't see it as just a class.

I did manage to get the details about the error by reopening Visual studio and debugging again:
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'WindowsFormsAutoClick.Form1' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: Type initializer is CLR parlance for the static constructor for the class. If you don't have an explicit one, look at the initializers for static fields within the class, because they go into the static constructor too.

Comment: I think I solved it because some of the variables didn't have to be static so I changed that, but now I am having other issues where the program gets stuck somewhere and isn't opening at all. So I can't check yet if I really solved that error.

Comment: Just changing them from static to non-static will move *when* the exception is thrown but not fix the fact that the initializer throws exceptions.

Comment: That makes sence, because the problem where the program isn't starting at all is probably the same issue. I found out that I have some infinite loop where I add a new key to the dictionary and creating that key will create another and so on. I don't have time to fix that now, so I will get back with how that turns out.

Comment: `public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); if (CurrentSelections == null) CurrentSelections = new Selections(); else Console.WriteLine("More then one current selections variables"); }`
While CurrentSelections is a static variable in the class Form1 and the Selections class arrives from Form1. This is what actually caused a memory leak and prevented the form for completing start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializer error information is also shown in Class[Design]. Making the variable non-static will move when the exception is thrown which helped me finding the cause of the exception.

Turns out I was assigning a value while in an initializing phase of a control component to a variable which wasn't created yet.